# How to deploy NodeJS/React app to Heroku with yarn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I've already followed the instructions on heroku and researched a few hours to find the issue about the deployment to heroku.
Whenever I push the repository to heroku, the build fails at building fresh packages.

I am using the yarn package manager and added a lot of dependencies to my app. I added one dependency with NPM and prohibit to choose two package manager for developing . .. 
I already removed the package-lock.json files and changed the package.json with the scripts to the according package manager I use for my app.

```
{
  "name": "real-world",
  "version": "1",
  "description": "MERN",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "Le, Vu Minh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "yarn --cwd frontend install",
    "start": "node ./app.js",
    "server": "node ./app.js",
    "client": "yarn --cwd ./frontend run start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn run server\" \"yarn run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn install && yarn --cwd ./frontend install && yarn --cwd ./frontend run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "yarn": "1.19.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "jshint": "^2.10.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt": "^0.2.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.4",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve": "^11.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.3"
  }
}
```

That is the output, when I push to the heroku master branch.

```
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.16.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  1.19.0
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 10.16.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.16.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.9.0
remote:        Resolving yarn version 1.19.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (1.19.0)...
remote:        Installed yarn 1.19.0
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v1.19.0
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        error /tmp/build_8fb6cb960e5fba9ed79ab935cf0403ce/node_modules/node-base64: Command failed.
remote:        Exit code: 127
remote:        Command: ./install.sh
remote:        Arguments:
remote:        Directory: /tmp/build_8fb6cb960e5fba9ed79ab935cf0403ce/node_modules/node-base64
remote:        Output:
remote:        ./install.sh: 3: ./install.sh: node-waf: not found
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: your `./install.sh` file is not found

Answer (score 0):

You should remove package-lock.json and include a yarn.lock instead and heroku will deploy using yarn instead of npm.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem: a locally app with ReactJS using yarn working locally, but the deploy to Heroku did not work. I reviewed several post like these and tried some tutorials, without luck.

I think that with Heroku is better to follow the official documentation. What I did: I follow this tutorial that deploy a simple React app in Heroku and then I put my code in this app:

- https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration